# Servlet response in Window.open() in gwt

Tags: servlets, gwt

How can I get the status of Window.open() in gwt? I did not found any way to get the response from the server. Let say there is session timeout in server and I tried to open url using Window.open() so in this scenario how can I verify there is session timeout on server. So I can redirect user to login screen.

Answer (score 0):

To get response from the server you need to use Ajax (f.e. via RequestBuilder).

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "<URL>");

rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        // do what you want with status code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
    }
});

rb.send();
```